# WCFM Auto Set or attached Category everytime adding a product

Tags: javascript, woocommerce

It have category called "peak". everytime I add a new product, I want a "peak" category will automatically attached without manually selecting it or consider it as my default value.

How can I achieved using javascript. Please help.

Here's my html looks like:

```
<span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--default select2-container--below" dir="ltr" style="width: 100%;">
<span class="selection"><span class="select2-selection select2-selection--multiple" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="-1">
<ul class="select2-selection__rendered">
<li class="select2-selection__choice" title="peak"><span class="select2-selection__choice__remove" role="presentation">×</span>peak</li>
<li class="select2-search select2-search--inline"><input class="select2-search__field" type="search" tabindex="0" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="list" placeholder="" style="width: 3.75em;"></li>
</ul></span>
</span><span class="dropdown-wrapper" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>
```

Comment: Please explain some more, examples, code, etc.

Comment: Hi  iAmOren Thank you for speedy reply. a "peak" category is considering as my default value everytime I added a new product: 

I updated my post to show my HTML looks like.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about WooCommerce, therefore I don't know how you intend to include your JavaScript snippet into the larger picture. But assuming that WCFM has already created a select2 structure for you without the "peak" category in it you could trigger the function `addPeak()` as shown below. This will insert your category-`<li>` into the select2 structure.

In my sample code I trigger the function through a button click and use a trivial CSS-selector ('ul') to find the parent element. These things need to be adjusted (refined) in your target code.

```js
document.querySelector('button').onclick=()=>addPeak('ul');

function addPeak(sel){
  let ul=document.querySelector(sel);
  if (ul) ul.innerHTML='<li class="select2-selection__choice" title="peak"><span class="select2-selection__choice__remove" role="presentation">×</span>peak</li>'+
ul.innerHTML;

}
```

```html
<span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--default select2-container--below" dir="ltr" style="width: 100%;">
<span class="selection"><span class="select2-selection select2-selection--multiple" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="-1">
<ul class="select2-selection__rendered">
<li class="select2-selection__choice" title="other"><span class="select2-selection__choice__remove" role="presentation">×</span>other</li>
<li class="select2-search select2-search--inline"><input class="select2-search__field" type="search" tabindex="0" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="list" placeholder="" style="width: 3.75em;"></li>
</ul></span>
</span><span class="dropdown-wrapper" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>
<button> test </button>
```

Comment: Thanks you car10m trying for helping me, Unfortunately I test your code but it doesnt work.

Comment: I hope you have used it in a modified way, as you will need to supply a "more qualified" CSS-selector to identify the parent-`<ul>`. And in case there are problems: have a look in your console window to learn more about it.